# JavaScript to output html range slider values for multiple sliders

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create two range sliders in html and display their current value with a JS script below each slider. But in my code both sliders will output their value to the same "value output" (the one for the slider with `id="myRange2"`). Why does this happen and how can I fix this?

[image]

I tried to make the `slider` and `output` variables unique for each slider script, but that does not solve my problem.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26564274/html-javascript-range-slider) issue is similar, but I am not so familiar with JS and I think my solution might be more simple.

This is my `.html` code with the JS scripts at the end:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>

<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange2">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo2"></span></p>
</div>

<script>
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
</script>

<script>
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange2");
var output = document.getElementById("demo2");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As said below, your variable names are causing your issue.  You might have seen this a bit more clearly had you not used two <script></script> tags.  You don't need to put them back to back like you did.  One would suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use different names for variables

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>

<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange2">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo2"></span></p>
</div>

<script>
var slider1 = document.getElementById("myRange");
var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
demo.innerHTML = slider1.value;

slider1.oninput = function() {
  demo.innerHTML = this.value;
}
</script>

<script>
var slider2 = document.getElementById("myRange2");
var output = document.getElementById("demo2");
output.innerHTML = slider2.value;

slider2.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, I just edited the lines `demo.innerHTML = this.value;` and `demo2.innerHTML = this.value;` which also worked for some reason