# javascript / ESP8266 - trying to move two servos using sliders

Tags: javascript, slider, move, esp8266, servo

I'm trying to use an ESP8266 with two servos attached to control the servos using the sliders from the web interface.
The sliders are there, the first slider works perfectly to move the first servo, unfortunately the second slider doesn't move the second servo.

This is the code on the arduino:

```
 
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
//----------------------------------------Include the Servo Library
#include <Servo.h>

#include "PageIndex.h"; //--> Include the contents of the User Interface Web page, stored in the same folder as the .ino file

#define LEDonBoard 2  //--> Defining an On Board LED, used for indicators when the process of connecting to a wifi router
#define ServoPort D1    //--> Defining Servo Port
#define ServoPort2 D3    //--> Defining Servo Port

//----------------------------------------SSID and Password of your WiFi router
const char *ssid = "wifi_router";
const char *password = "wifi_password";
//----------------------------------------

Servo myservo;  //--> create servo object to control a servo
Servo myservo2;  //--> create servo2 object to control a servo2

ESP8266WebServer server(80);  //--> Server on port 80

//----------------------------------------This routine is executed when you open NodeMCU ESP8266 IP Address in browser
void handleRoot() {
 String s = MAIN_page; //Read HTML contents
 server.send(200, "text/html", s); //Send web page
}
//----------------------------------------

//----------------------------------------Procedure for handling servo control
void handleServo(){
  String POS = server.arg("servoPOS");
  int pos = POS.toInt();
  myservo.write(pos);   //--> Move the servo motor according to the POS value
  delay(15);
  Serial.print("Servo Angle:");
  Serial.println(pos);
  server.send(200, "text/plane","");
}

void handleServo2(){
  String POS2 = server.arg("servoPOS2");
  int pos2 = POS2.toInt();
  myservo2.write(pos2);   //--> Move the servo2 motor according to the POS2 value
  delay(15);
  Serial.print("Servo2 Angle:");
  Serial.println(pos2);
  server.send(200, "text/plane","");
}
//----------------------------------------
//----------------------------------------Setup----------------------------------------
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(1000);
  
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password); //--> Connect to your WiFi router
  Serial.println("");
    
  pinMode(LEDonBoard,OUTPUT); //--> On Board LED port Direction output
  digitalWrite(LEDonBoard, HIGH); //--> Turn off Led On Board

  myservo.attach(ServoPort); //--> attaches the servo on D1 to the servo object
  myservo2.attach(ServoPort2); //--> attaches the servo on D1 to the servo object
  //----------------------------------------Wait for connection
  Serial.print("Connecting");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    //----------------------------------------Make the On Board Flashing LED on the process of connecting to the wifi router.
    digitalWrite(LEDonBoard, LOW);
    delay(250);
    digitalWrite(LEDonBoard, HIGH);
    delay(250);
    //----------------------------------------
  }
  //----------------------------------------
  digitalWrite(LEDonBoard, HIGH); //--> Turn off the On Board LED when it is connected to the wifi router.
  //----------------------------------------If connection successful show IP address in serial monitor
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Successfully connected to : ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  //----------------------------------------

  //----------------------------------------Initialize Webserver
  server.on("/",handleRoot);  //--> Routine to handle at root location. This is to display web page.
  server.on("/setPOS",handleServo); //--> Sets servo position from Web request
  server.on("/setPOS2",handleServo2); //--> Sets servo position from Web request
  server.begin();  
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//----------------------------------------Loop----------------------------------------
void loop() {
 server.handleClient();
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And this is the PageIndex.h file accompanied by the .ino file.

```
const char MAIN_page[] PROGMEM = R"=====(
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
      html {
        font-family: Arial;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0px auto;
        text-align: center;
      }
      
      .slidecontainer {
        width: 100%;
      }

      .slider {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        width: 50%;
        height: 15px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background: #d3d3d3;
        outline: none;
        opacity: 0.7;
        -webkit-transition: .2s;
        transition: opacity .2s;
      }

      .slider:hover {
        opacity: 1;
      }

      .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: #4CAF50;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      .slider::-moz-range-thumb {
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: #4CAF50;
        cursor: pointer;
      }



 .slider2 {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        width: 50%;
        height: 15px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background: #d3d3d3;
        outline: none;
        opacity: 0.7;
        -webkit-transition: .2s;
        transition: opacity .2s;
      }

      .slider2:hover {
        opacity: 1;
      }

      .slider2::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: #4CAF50;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      .slider2::-moz-range-thumb {
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: #4CAF50;
        cursor: pointer;
      }



      
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>NodeMCU ESP8266 / ESP12E Control Servo SG90</h1>
    <br><br>
    <div class="slidecontainer">
      <input type="range" min="0" max="180" value="90" class="slider" id="myRange">
      <p>Value : <span id="demo"></span></p>
    </div>



    <div class="slidecontainer">
      <input type="range" min="0" max="180" value="20" class="slider" id="myRange2">
      <p>Value : <span id="demo2"></span></p>
    </div>


    <script>

      function sendData(pos) {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            console.log(this.responseText);
          }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "setPOS?servoPOS="+pos, true);
        xhttp.send();
      } 
      var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
      var output = document.getElementById("demo");
      output.innerHTML = slider.value;

      slider.oninput = function() {
        output.innerHTML = this.value;
        sendData(output.innerHTML);
      }
   
     </script>
     
     
<script>

  function sendData(pos) {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            console.log(this.responseText);
          }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "setPOS2?servoPOS2="+pos2, true);
        xhttp.send();
      } 
      var slider2 = document.getElementById("myRang2e");
      var output2 = document.getElementById("demo2");
      output2.innerHTML2 = slider2.value;

      slider2.oninput = function() {
        output2.innerHTML = this.value;
        sendData(output2.innerHTML);
      }
      
</script>


  </body>
</html>
)=====";
```

I tried to compose the code based on the first servo, changing some values from 'servo' to 'servo2' but it didn't helped.
Similar issue found here:
[JavaScript to output html range slider values for multiple sliders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56562129/javascript-to-output-html-range-slider-values-for-multiple-sliders)
But still didn't got it to work...

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: At the least, using the same name, `sendData()`, for two functions isn't going to work well. Have you looked at errors and warnings in the browser console?

Comment: I tried changing second sendData() to sendData2() but that didn't worked out... no related browser errors..